# UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync Hangs and doesn't return (MVC5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I need to implement the Forgot Password feature using Asp.Net Identity 2.1.0, but the UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync hangs and never returns, I even tried UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id) but to no avail.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserId);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.");
                return View();
            }
             //Send an email with this link
             string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
             var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);     
             await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
             return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have no clue as to what is missing, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved it. I created another empty project and saw that the UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id) was working fine there. I removed the Microsoft.Identity.Core and other relevant packages from the other project and re-added and now its working like a charm.